# CodeName as constant?

Tags: excel, vba, constants, excel-2016

I have multiple functions/procedures in an [Excel 2016 VBA module](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244387/send-http-request-for-each-row-in-excel-table/244459#244459) that reference a CodeName called `DataSheet`.

```
Public Sub LoadRecords()
    '***Caution: The 'DataSheet' CodeName is hardcoded (in multiple places).***
    With DataSheet.ListObjects(tblName)
        'Some code 
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function ConcatVars(RowNum As Integer) As String
    '***Caution: The 'DataSheet' CodeName is hardcoded (in multiple places).***
    For Each Column In DataSheet.ListObjects(tblName).ListColumns
        'Some code
    Next
End Function
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to declare the CodeName as a constant?

- Reason: If the CodeName were to be changed, the references in the VBA code could be updated in a single, highly-noticable place.

---

**What I've tried:**

If I put the codeName in a constant:

```
Public Const codeName = "DataSheet"
```

And try to reference the constant:

```
With codeName.ListObjects(tblName)
```

I get this error:

> Compile Error: Invalid qualifier

Comment: The main point about using the codename vs. the tab name is you *don't* change the codename (and your users cannot accidentally change it).  If you wanted something like this you can define a function which returns the sheet: the codename would only need to be defined in that function.

Comment: Just seeing your comment with same idea as my answer :)

Comment: Also worth noting that if you (for example) add any controls to the worksheet which you might refer to as (eg)  `DataSheet.lstNames` then that may cause problems if you instead use a generic "worksheet" variable in its place (because the OOB worksheet does not have a `lstNames` member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a function (and avoid to overload existing CodeName property with identical function or variable name):

```
Function myCodeName() As Worksheet
Set myCodeName = DataSheet          ' << change to your project's Code(Name) 
'Debug.Print myCodeName.CodeName
End Function
```